# Moving a player with GUI Texture

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have a GUI Texture and the following script is attach to it:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class moveUP : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed=3f;
    public GameObject player;
    void OnGUI() {
           if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            player.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

It works not only when I click the GUI Texture, but also whereever I click on the screen.

How can I fix this?

Or if you have any other script for moving a player with GUI Texture feel free to share it with me.

Comment: You are currently checking if the left mouse button is down, move.... You should also check to see if the mouse position is inside the gui texture... You do this by use the gui textures Rect and using the .contains(event.current.mousePosition); understand?

Answer (score 1):

Change `OnGUI` to `Update`

```cs
void Update() {
       if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        player.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `OnMouseDown()?`

`OnMouseDown()` is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity documentation says that the `Input.GetMouseDown` function must be called from the `Update()` routine. So as Savlon says, that function will run whenever you click with the mouse, regardless of where you do it, so you should use events for the GUI.

Therefore, you must use the interface `IPointerDownHandler` and implements its method `OnPointerDown()`.

```
public class moveUP : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    ...

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        //Do something, like move...
    }
}
```

The script must have the element that you want the behavior to have. For more details see unity's documentation on events in UnityEngine.EventSystems.